# Including only current user's posts in search

Tags: wp-query, search, actions, capabilities, pre-get-posts

I am a new WP plugin developer. I want the search page to include only the current user's posts.

I first added a new capability `read_others_posts` to only administrators and editors. Then I tried the following code, placing it in a function and hooking it to the `pre_get_posts` action:

```
if( !current_user_can('read_others_posts') )
    $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
```

For all other queries (including in admin and in home), this "filter" works but search doesn't. It still shows all posts on the result page.

Is there something that I did wrong? Is there a way to achieve what I described?

**EDIT:**

Just in case anyone wants to use this hook, let me provide a more general purpose version of the function, although I do think there is a better way to achieve this:

```
function exclude_other_users_posts( $query ) {
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // guests cannot read private posts
        // and we exclude all public posts here
        // so guests can read nothing :-)
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'private' );
        $query->set( 'perm', 'readable' );
    } elseif( !current_user_can('read_others_posts') )
        $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_other_users_posts' );
```

Comment: Wicked. That should work, afaik.

Comment: can you post the whole function

Comment: That was the whole function body actually. The rest is just giving it a name and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing, the problem was found to be caused by another filter, `posts_where`, which was registered to support searching also in custom fields, and that's why only searching is affected.

Originally it generates something like this, so if the `OR` statement returns true (when one of the custom fields includes `foo`), that post will appear on the result page:

```
AND wp_posts.post_author IN (2) AND (
    (
        (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%foo%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%foo%')
    )
) AND ( /* wordpress stuff... */ ) OR ( /* section the filter generates... */ )
```

I have modified so that this filter returns:

```
AND wp_posts.post_author IN (2) AND (
    (
        (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%foo%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%foo%')
        OR ( /* section the filter generates... */ )
    )
) AND ( /* wordpress stuff */ )
```

Thanks to Johannes for giving me ideas that the original code should work :)

Comment: You could also add query parameters to the search.php query

Comment: You mean I could edit the core? I am trying my best not to do that as I want to distribute the plugin.

Comment: Modify the search.php file which you can copy over to your child theme